# The Bhumi Geetha

Tags: kali-yuga, cosmology

What is Bhumi Geetha and what is its effect in the present kali yuga? What is the universal history the special qualities of each age, movement of time, cosmic maintenance influenced in the Bhumi Geetha?

Comment: What is `Bhumi Geetha`? Hearing for the first time. No wiki article except [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhoomi_Geetha).

Comment: @iammilind--Will provide the answer in few hours

Comment: It looks like the Bhumigita is from Shrimad Bhagavatam book 12 chapter 3. http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/bhUmigIta.html?lang=sa

Comment: You are right Gabe

Answer (score 3):

[Shrimad Bhagavatham Canto 12-3](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3) is Bhumi Gita.

> This chapter describes  how the earth took note of the foolishness of
>   the many kings bent on conquering her. It also describes how even
>   though the Age of Kali is full of faults, the glorification of the
>   name of Lord Hari destroys them all. Nama Sankeertan is the easy way
>   to reach the abode of Lord Narayana.  Chanting Hare Rama Hara Rama
>   Rama Rama Hare Hare   Hare Krishna Hare Krishna Krishna Krishna Hare
>   Hare daily at your free time travel time will lead you to a peaceful
>   life.
>
> Great kings, who are actually just playthings of death, desire to
>   subdue their six internal enemies — the five senses and the mind — and
>   afterward they imagine they will go on to conquer the earth and all
>   its oceans. Seeing their false hopes, the earth simply laughs, for
>   eventually they all must leave this planet and go elsewhere, as have
>   all the great kings and monarchs of the past. Moreover, after usurping
>   the earth or some part of it — which is actually unconquerable and
>   must in every case be given up — fathers, sons, brothers, friends and
>   relatives quarrel over it.
>
> Thus the study of history naturally leads to the conclusion that all
>   worldly achievements are temporary, and this conclusion should give
>   rise to a sense of renunciation. Ultimately, the highest goal of life
>   for any living entity is pure devotion to Lord Kṛishna which
>   annihilates all inauspiciousness. In the age of Satya, religion was
>   complete, still possessing its four legs of truth, mercy, austerity
>   and charity. With the coming of each succeeding age, starting with
>   Treta, these religious qualities each diminish by one quarter.
>
> In Kali-yuga the legs of religion retain only one fourth of their
>   power, and even that will be lost with the progress of the age. The
>   mode of goodness is predominant during Satya-yuga, and the mode of
>   passion is predominant during the Treta-yuga. The mixed modes of
>   passion and ignorance are predominant during Dvapara-yuga, and in the
>   Age of Kali the mode of ignorance is predominant. Atheism, the
>   smallness and inferiority of all things, and devotion to the genitals
>   and belly are very much evident in the Age of Kali. Living entities
>   contaminated by the influence of Kali do not worship the Supreme Lord,
>   Sri Hari, even though they can be freed from all bondage and easily
>   achieve the supreme destination simply by chanting the glories of His
>   name and taking shelter of Him. But if somehow or other the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead becomes manifest within the hearts of the
>   conditioned souls in Kali-yuga, then all faults of place, time and
>   personality inherent in the age will be destroyed.
>
> Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults, but it possesses one great quality:
>   simply by the chanting of the name of Kṛishna, one can be delivered
>   from material association and attain the Absolute Truth. All that was
>   accomplished in the age of Satya by meditation, in the age of Tretā by
>   sacrificial performances and in the age of Dvāpara by temple worship
>   is easily gained during the Kali-yuga by the simple process of
>   hari-kirtana.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  Plagarism is not allowed on any sites. What the answers given by you are all copied only. You have not invented anything new. you might have modified prepositions, add punctuations etc.  As I already told you destroy the answers given. Nobody writes on his own. Answers  are being referred in puranas and reproduced.

Comment: Use blockquotes when you copy something from external site or scripture. It makes it clear to read.

Comment: @the destroyer   ok